# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'avatar_url' in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def avatar(self, ctx, *,  avamember : discord.Member=None):
    userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
    await ctx.send(userAvatarUrl)
```

Hi, the code above is what I'm using in discord.py. I'm trying to display the avatar, but it won't work. What I get instead is: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'`.

What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Check for `None` before trying to access `.avatar_url`?

Comment: How are you invoking this command? Is it in a Cog?

Answer (score 1):

You set `avamember` to `None` in the function declaration and then tried to access an attribute. Since `avamember is None`, it has no such attribute. To fix this, get an actual `discord.Member` object.

Edit: I'm assuming that object in fact has the requested attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you invoked your command wrong. To get the `discord.Member` object you have to mention the user, otherwise, it will return `None`.

Delete the `*` and `self` (unless it's in a [cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cog)). In this case `discord.Member=None` is kinda useless too (unless you want to use it to check if the command was used correctly).

```py
@client.command()
async def avatar(ctx, avamember : discord.Member):
    userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
    await ctx.send(userAvatarUrl)
```

Then use your command properly:

[image: screenshot image]

---

***If your command is in the [Cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cog):***

1. Change `@client.command()` to `@commands.command()`
2. Add `self` before `ctx` as you had.

Answer (score 0):

You set `avamember` to `None` therefore if you do not pass a user it will then throw an error, so make sure you invoke it correctly.

I advise changing it to to avoid the error:

```py
async def avatar(self, ctx, *, avamember: discord.Member):
```

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 mistakes, first you've put self in parameter but you've used `@client.command()` instead of `@commands.command()`, if you intent to use it as cog then replace `client.command()` with `@commands.command()`, else remove self from the parameter and second you initialized thie member as none `discord.Member=None` without any missing args error

Use this, this will work

```
@client.command()
async def avatar(ctx, *, avamember : discord.Member):
    userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
    await ctx.send(userAvatarUrl)
```

if you want to send an error if the user is not specified then you this

```
@client.command()
async def avatar(ctx, *, avamember: discord.Member = None):
    if avamember == None:
        await ctx.send('Please specify a user!')
    else:
        userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
        await ctx.send(userAvatarUrl)
```